# How to scale to certain element in a iframe responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've tried several ways to scale to HTML-element within the iframe which opening not on same domain

It`s works fine with wrapped div which has transform scale attribute

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <iframe class="scaled" src="frame.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scale(4,33) translateY(-107px) translateX(-240px);
}

iframe.scaled {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px; 
}
```

My question is how i can make this responsive? that the scaling was the same on all devices (mobile), i guess we need some javascript code to do this?

Comment: What do you want to be responsive, the `iframe` or a `div` inside the `iframe`?

Comment: You can't do anything inside the iframe due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: @NeilPatrao content inside the iframe

Comment: Easiest option would be to use jQuery to modify the css property. But I'm not sure why you want to use the transform scale property. There are responsive frameworks like bootstrap. If you have control over the contents of the iframe, use a responsive framework inside and that should help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use pure HTML.

The purpose of this code is to set bottom padding to the aspect ratio of the video or iframe. The iframe is then scaled to 100%, in both width and height, which completely fills the outer container. The outer container is now able to atuomatically adjust it's height according to it's width and the iframe adjust accordingly.

```html
<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:0px; padding-bottom:56.25%;">
    <iframe style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%"
        src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

**JsFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lmjb3ge/

I hope this answers your question.